# FactoryGirl not deleting user after test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I was running tests, and first time round, they all pass green. If I run the test again, some fail with the following message:

```
 Failure/Error: @user = Factory :user
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

I am really confused as to why this is happening. I thought rspec did not push values to the database. If I purge the test database, this is fixed, but then, on second round of test execution, some fail with the same error.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Note, I installed cancan gem recently, maybe it has to do something with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory Girl is not what is supposed to be deleting the data, it's usually RSpec (by way of the `use_transactional_fixtures` option) or another tool like `database_cleaner`.

If your test database is not being cleaned out correctly, then I would recommend using the [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner).

Comment: I will give database_cleaner a try. I do have use_transactional_fixtures=true tho. Shouldnt it be fine with that option?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few cases where things didn't clear out properly, and running `rake db:test:prepare` to clean out the database worked like a charm (assuming you aren't pre-populating with data).  If you do need pre-populated data, use fixtures or other similar solutions to reset to a pristine state.